# Multiplication table with lines (python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a multiplication table in the following format:

```
  | 1  2 ...  9
---------...----
1 | 1  2 ...  9
2 | 2  4 ... 18
...
9 | 9 18 ... 81
```

- Properly align numbers to the right
- vertical line after first column and horizontal line after first row.

(the `...` are just here for brevity)

So far I figured out the alignment:

```
for row in range(1,10):
    s = ''
    for col in range(1,10):
        s += '{:3} '.format(row * col)
    print(s, sep="\t")
```

But how do I add the lines, i.e. they shouldn't be iterated in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
for row in range(1,10):
    s = str(row) + '  |'
    if(row == 1):
        for i in range(1, 2):
            x = ' ' + '  |'
            for j in range(1, 10):
                x += '{:3} '.format(i * j)
            print(x, sep="\t")
        print('----' * 10)
    for col in range(1,10):
        s += '{:3} '.format(row * col)
    print(s, sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
   |  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
----------------------------------------
1  |  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
2  |  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18 
3  |  3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27 
4  |  4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36 
5  |  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45 
6  |  6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54 
7  |  7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63 
8  |  8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72 
9  |  9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```